# How to merge Lucene index files?

Tags: list, ocaml

I am trying to make a list of pairs in ocaml, but the problem is when the lists' length are different i don't hot to make pairs (a,b) when one of the elements doesn't exist.

Comment: Please add example input and expected output, also please share the code that you have already written.

Comment: Alex, pretend you're us, what have you given us to go off of besides "please write this code for me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you'll have to create a type to encapsulate the situations of the differing length,

```
 type ('a,'b) combined = Both of 'a * 'b | Left of 'a | Right of 'b

 let rec zipwith xs ys = match xs,ys with
   | x::xs,y::ys -> Both (x,y) :: (zipwith xs ys)
   | x::xs, []   -> Left x     :: (zipwith xs ys)
   | [], y::ys   -> Right y    :: (zipwith xs ys)
   | [], []      -> []

 # zipwith [1;2;3] [1;2];;
 - : (int, int) combined list = [Both (1, 1); Both (2, 2); Left 3]
```

You'll have to make optimizations regarding tail-calls for this to work on long lists, but this is a start of how to approach the problem.